# Magento 2 : Can't able to override controller

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, controllers

I need to override this below controller :

> Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate.php

But, I can't able to override. I need to customize **checkUniqueOption()** function.

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate" type="Vendor\Magento\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate" />
```

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use preference for overiding..

Comment: Yes. I already used. But, can't able to call my checkUniqueOption() code.

Comment: @aravind Can you please give me demo?

Comment: i have updated it..It's for Magento 2.3.. If you any other version replace with that code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to update **checkUniqueOption()**  this function and because of that function is ***private*** you need to rename this as **_checkUniqueOption()** or something else, and in that file there are some other functions which are also private so you need to do same thing for that all functions as well. So your new Controller file's content will be :

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Validate.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\FormData;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute as AttributeAction;

class Validate extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate
{
    const DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY = 'message';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $multipleAttributeList;

    /**
     * @var FormData|null
     */
    private $formDataSerializer;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $attributeLabelCache
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param array $multipleAttributeList
     * @param FormData|null $formDataSerializer
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $attributeLabelCache,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        array $multipleAttributeList = [],
        FormData $formDataSerializer = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $attributeLabelCache, $coreRegistry, $resultPageFactory, $resultJsonFactory, $layoutFactory, $multipleAttributeList, $formDataSerializer);
        $this->multipleAttributeList = $multipleAttributeList;
        $this->formDataSerializer = $formDataSerializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(FormData::class);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $response = new DataObject();
        $response->setError(false);
        try {
            $optionsData = $this->formDataSerializer
                ->unserialize($this->getRequest()->getParam('serialized_options', '[]'));
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            $message = __("The attribute couldn't be validated due to an error. Verify your information and try again. "
                . "If the error persists, please try again later.");
            $this->_setMessageToResponse($response, [$message]);
            $response->setError(true);
        }

        $attributeCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code');
        $frontendLabel = $this->getRequest()->getParam('frontend_label');
        $attributeCode = $attributeCode ?: $this->generateCode($frontendLabel[0]);
        $attributeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
        $attribute = $this->_objectManager->create(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::class
        )->loadByCode(
            $this->_entityTypeId,
            $attributeCode
        );

        if ($attribute->getId() && !$attributeId || $attributeCode === 'product_type') {
            $message = strlen($this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code'))
                ? __('An attribute with this code already exists.')
                : __('An attribute with the same code (%1) already exists.', $attributeCode);

            $this->_setMessageToResponse($response, [$message]);

            $response->setError(true);
            $response->setProductAttribute($attribute->toArray());
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->has('new_attribute_set_name')) {
            $setName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_attribute_set_name');
            /** @var $attributeSet \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set */
            $attributeSet = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::class);
            $attributeSet->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId)->load($setName, 'attribute_set_name');
            if ($attributeSet->getId()) {
                $setName = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($setName);
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An attribute set named \'%1\' already exists.', $setName));

                $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
                $layout->initMessages();
                $response->setError(true);
                $response->setHtmlMessage($layout->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
            }
        }

        $multipleOption = $this->getRequest()->getParam("frontend_input");
        $multipleOption = (null === $multipleOption) ? 'select' : $multipleOption;

        if (isset($this->multipleAttributeList[$multipleOption])) {
            $options = $optionsData[$this->multipleAttributeList[$multipleOption]] ?? null;
            $this->_checkUniqueOption(
                $response,
                $options
            );
            $valueOptions = (isset($options['value']) && is_array($options['value'])) ? $options['value'] : [];
            foreach (array_keys($valueOptions) as $key) {
                if (!empty($options['delete'][$key])) {
                    unset($valueOptions[$key]);
                }
            }
            $this->_checkEmptyOption($response, $valueOptions);
        }

        return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setJsonData($response->toJson());
    }

    /**
     * Throws Exception if not unique values into options.
     *
     * @param array $optionsValues
     * @param array $deletedOptions
     * @return bool
     */
    private function _isUniqueAdminValues(array $optionsValues, array $deletedOptions)
    {
        $adminValues = [];
        foreach ($optionsValues as $optionKey => $values) {
            if (!(isset($deletedOptions[$optionKey]) && $deletedOptions[$optionKey] === '1')) {
                $adminValues[] = reset($values);
            }
        }
        $uniqueValues = array_unique($adminValues);
        return array_diff_assoc($adminValues, $uniqueValues);
    }

    /**
     * Set message to response object
     *
     * @param DataObject $response
     * @param string[] $messages
     * @return DataObject
     */
    private function _setMessageToResponse($response, $messages)
    {
        $messageKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message_key', static::DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY);
        if ($messageKey === static::DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY) {
            $messages = reset($messages);
        }
        return $response->setData($messageKey, $messages);
    }

    /**
     * Performs checking the uniqueness of the attribute options.
     *
     * @param DataObject $response
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return $this
     */
    private function _checkUniqueOption(DataObject $response, array $options = null)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/checkUniqueOption.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('checkUniqueOption Log'); // Simple Text Log

        if (is_array($options)
            && isset($options['value'])
            && isset($options['delete'])
            && !empty($options['value'])
            && !empty($options['delete'])
        ) {
            $duplicates = $this->_isUniqueAdminValues($options['value'], $options['delete']);
            if (!empty($duplicates)) {
                $this->_setMessageToResponse(
                    $response,
                    [__('The value of Admin must be unique. (%1)', implode(', ', $duplicates))]
                );
                $response->setError(true);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Check that admin does not try to create option with empty admin scope option.
     *
     * @param DataObject $response
     * @param array $optionsForCheck
     * @return void
     */
    private function _checkEmptyOption(DataObject $response, array $optionsForCheck = null)
    {
        foreach ($optionsForCheck as $optionValues) {
            if (isset($optionValues[0]) && $optionValues[0] == '') {
                $this->_setMessageToResponse($response, [__("The value of Admin scope can't be empty.")]);
                $response->setError(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Nope. not working.

Comment: There are no any class available : Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Code

Comment: Which version of Magento you're using ?

Comment: 2.3.1 .........

Comment: I've updated code as per M2.3.1 version.

Comment: only execute() function called. Can't call _checkUniqueOption() function.

Comment: What error you're getting then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99867/discussion-between-niket-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate" />
</config>
```

In Your Controller file copy paste the entire content from core file.

Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Validate.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

use Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute as AttributeAction;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Code as AttributeCodeValidator;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\FormData;

class Validate extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate
{
   const DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY = 'message';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
 */
protected $resultJsonFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
 */
protected $layoutFactory;

/**
 * @var array
 */
private $multipleAttributeList;

/**
 * @var FormData|null
 */
private $formDataSerializer;

/**
 * @var AttributeCodeValidator
 */
private $attributeCodeValidator;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $attributeLabelCache
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
 * @param array $multipleAttributeList
 * @param FormData|null $formDataSerializer
 * @param AttributeCodeValidator|null $attributeCodeValidator
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $attributeLabelCache,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
    array $multipleAttributeList = [],
    FormData $formDataSerializer = null,
    AttributeCodeValidator $attributeCodeValidator = null
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $attributeLabelCache, $coreRegistry, $resultPageFactory);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    $this->multipleAttributeList = $multipleAttributeList;
    $this->formDataSerializer = $formDataSerializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(FormData::class);
    $this->attributeCodeValidator = $attributeCodeValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
        AttributeCodeValidator::class
    );
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $response = new DataObject();
    $response->setError(false);
    try {
        $optionsData = $this->formDataSerializer
            ->unserialize($this->getRequest()->getParam('serialized_options', '[]'));
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $message = __("The attribute couldn't be validated due to an error. Verify your information and try again. "
            . "If the error persists, please try again later.");
        $this->setMessageToResponse($response, [$message]);
        $response->setError(true);
    }

    $attributeCode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code');
    $frontendLabel = $this->getRequest()->getParam('frontend_label');
    $attributeCode = $attributeCode ?: $this->generateCode($frontendLabel[0]);
    $attributeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
    $attribute = $this->_objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::class
    )->loadByCode(
        $this->_entityTypeId,
        $attributeCode
    );

    if ($attribute->getId() && !$attributeId || $attributeCode === 'product_type' || $attributeCode === 'type_id') {
        $message = strlen($this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code'))
            ? __('An attribute with this code already exists.')
            : __('An attribute with the same code (%1) already exists.', $attributeCode);

        $this->setMessageToResponse($response, [$message]);

        $response->setError(true);
        $response->setProductAttribute($attribute->toArray());
    }

    if (!$this->attributeCodeValidator->isValid($attributeCode)) {
        $this->setMessageToResponse($response, $this->attributeCodeValidator->getMessages());
        $response->setError(true);
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->has('new_attribute_set_name')) {
        $setName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_attribute_set_name');
        /** @var $attributeSet \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set::class);
        $attributeSet->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId)->load($setName, 'attribute_set_name');
        if ($attributeSet->getId()) {
            $setName = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class)->escapeHtml($setName);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An attribute set named \'%1\' already exists.', $setName));

            $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
            $layout->initMessages();
            $response->setError(true);
            $response->setHtmlMessage($layout->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
        }
    }

    $multipleOption = $this->getRequest()->getParam("frontend_input");
    $multipleOption = (null === $multipleOption) ? 'select' : $multipleOption;

    if (isset($this->multipleAttributeList[$multipleOption])) {
        $options = $optionsData[$this->multipleAttributeList[$multipleOption]] ?? null;
        $this->checkUniqueOption(
            $response,
            $options
        );
        $valueOptions = (isset($options['value']) && is_array($options['value'])) ? $options['value'] : [];
        foreach (array_keys($valueOptions) as $key) {
            if (!empty($options['delete'][$key])) {
                unset($valueOptions[$key]);
            }
        }
        $this->checkEmptyOption($response, $valueOptions);
    }

    return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setJsonData($response->toJson());
}

/**
 * Throws Exception if not unique values into options.
 *
 * @param array $optionsValues
 * @param array $deletedOptions
 * @return bool
 */
private function isUniqueAdminValues(array $optionsValues, array $deletedOptions)
{
    $adminValues = [];
    foreach ($optionsValues as $optionKey => $values) {
        if (!(isset($deletedOptions[$optionKey]) && $deletedOptions[$optionKey] === '1')) {
            $adminValues[] = reset($values);
        }
    }
    $uniqueValues = array_unique($adminValues);
    return array_diff_assoc($adminValues, $uniqueValues);
}

/**
 * Set message to response object
 *
 * @param DataObject $response
 * @param string[] $messages
 * @return DataObject
 */
private function setMessageToResponse($response, $messages)
{
    $messageKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message_key', static::DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY);
    if ($messageKey === static::DEFAULT_MESSAGE_KEY) {
        $messages = reset($messages);
    }
    return $response->setData($messageKey, $messages);
}

/**
 * Performs checking the uniqueness of the attribute options.
 *
 * @param DataObject $response
 * @param array|null $options
 * @return $this
 */
private function checkUniqueOption(DataObject $response, array $options = null)
{
    if (is_array($options)
        && isset($options['value'])
        && isset($options['delete'])
        && !empty($options['value'])
        && !empty($options['delete'])
        && !empty($duplicates)
    ) {
        $duplicates = $this->isUniqueAdminValues($options['value'], $options['delete']);
        if (!empty($duplicates)) {
            $this->setMessageToResponse(
                $response,
                [__('The value of Admin must be unique. (%1)', implode(', ', $duplicates))]
            );
            $response->setError(true);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Check that admin does not try to create option with empty admin scope option.
 *
 * @param DataObject $response
 * @param array $optionsForCheck
 * @return void
 */
private function checkEmptyOption(DataObject $response, array $optionsForCheck = null)
{
    foreach ($optionsForCheck as $optionValues) {
        if (isset($optionValues[0]) && $optionValues[0] == '') {
            $this->setMessageToResponse($response, [__("The value of Admin scope can't be empty.")]);
            $response->setError(true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Did you checked from your side?

Comment: What do you need to overwrite in checkUniqueOption() ?

Comment: Need to add one condition with !empty($duplicates) condition

Comment: How can i check whether it's working or not?

Comment: Could you explain the test case?

Comment: edit any "Multiple Select" type product attribute and save record. For ex : material. It should be save successfully.

Comment: Ok will check that and update you..

Comment: Yes i have checked it's working by overiding using preference.. Wait i will update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99865/discussion-between-aravind-and-niket).